# Awk/Sed - how to print selection between two patterns?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, sed, awk

From reference: [catonmat.net](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/awk-one-liners-explained-part-three/) I think I could get the interested selection between two patterns using the following:

```
Source Text (one line): 6 June 2013 08.32.435 UTF+8 Report /content/folder[@name='....' Failure ....
```

Here the important part is the path to report , therefore I am using:

```
awk '/content\/folder\[@name=/,/Failure/' source.csv
```

I got the entire matched line, instead of only the content path between the two matches.

I have also tried to:

```
sed -n '/content\/folder\[@name/,/Failure/ {/content\/folder\[@name\|Failure/!p}' source.csv
```

Still returning the entire line...

What was wrong?

Comment: `/regexp/,/regexp/` is for selecting lines to process, not selecting substrings.

Comment: Are the 2 patterns always on the same line or could the start pattern be on a different line from the end pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -n '|content/folder\[@name.*Failure|s|.*content/folder\[@name\(.*\)Failure.*|\1|' source.csv
```

`/re1/,/re2/` is for selecting a range of lines, not a range of text within a line. Since `content/folder` and `Failure` are on the same line, you don't need a range, just a regex that matches a line containing both. Then use `s///` to extra the part between them.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's,.*/content/folder\[@name=\(.*\)Failure.*,\1,' source.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -Po '(?<=@name=).*(?=Failure)' source.csv
```